# How to clean-up file paths (back/forward slashes) provided as arguments in a .bat script to avoid syntax errors

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have a simple .bat script which renames all files in a folder using `ren`. The input argument is a path to a folder containing the files to be renamed. The script sometimes returns syntax errors which we've traced to the fact that sometimes the input path has forward slashes, backslashes, or a mix of both (and sometimes starts with a double forward slash). We would like to make this script more robust by allowing it to accept any of these types of paths, and cleaning up the path as part of the .bat script before calling the `ren` command.

So my question is: is there a (set of) command(s) I can apply to the file path argument (`%1` in the example below) before calling the `ren` function that will correct all forward/backslashes to be consistent and avoid syntax errors? I don't have much experience with .bat scripts, so any code examples would be helpful.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%F in (%1*.nc) do (
   for /F "tokens=1-8 delims=_" %%a in ("%%~nF") do (
   ren "%%F" "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e_%%g_%%f_%%h.nc"
   ) 
)
```

UPDATE: In the end, only the last suggestion by Magoo was needed, because changing `%1` to `"%~f1"` fixed the slash issues. I also had to add `%~f1\` to the first argument of the `ren` command because otherwise it was somehow looking in the wrong folder (the first `for` found the files ok, but the `ren` command was looking in the wrong folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%~f1\*.nc"') do (
   for /F "tokens=1-8 delims=_" %%a in ("%%~nF") do (
   ren "%~f1\%%~nF.nc" "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d_%%e_%%g_%%f_%%h.nc"
   ) 
)
```

Comment: Ah, yes! Good observation that `echo %~f1` corrects the slashes problem... happens every time I don't actually *TEST* the code - and I'd've not encountered the problem since I haven't touched \*Nix in *mumble* years, so I'd never have tried with `/` in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "corrected=%~1"
set "corrected=%corrected:/=\%"
```

Then use `%corrected%` in place of `%1` AND `quote the filename` thus:

```
for %%F in ("%corrected%*.nc") do (
```

If `%1` is always a directory-name, then add

```
if "%corrected:~-1%" neq "\" set "corrected=%corrected%\"
```

as a third `set` line before the `for` line.

The first `set` assigns the value of `%1` to a variable `corrected` - the `~` removes any enclosing quotes.

The second `set` changes all strings matching that between the `:` and `=` into that between the `=` and `%` in the variable given and assigns to the first-mentioned variable (can be the same variable, as in this case)

The third `set`, if used, checks that the last character is `\` and if it is not, appends a `\`.

The quoting of the filename-string allows there to be spaces in the path/filename and is harmless if there are no spaces.

To avoid attempting to rename a file twice, instead of

```
for %%F in ("%corrected%*.nc") do (
```

use

```
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%corrected%*.nc"') do (
```

This builds a list of filenames in memory, then processes that list.

Comment: This is almost working, thanks! I think the last step might not be 100% correct - this appears to be adding a second \ when the path already has a \ at the end...

Comment: It also seems like the script sometimes renames one of the files twice - somehow the loop is picking the already-renamed file a second time.

Comment: Batch is very sensitive to layout. Best to copy-paste than attempt to retype. The `adding extra "\"` issue is likely a difference between what I've posted and your code. Equally, the replacement `for` line is sensitive to - well - almost everything. The quotes, and type of quote for instance...

Comment: I'm still trying to get this to work. Is it correct that the last line of code you proposed should replace this line of code in my script? `for %%F in (%1*.nc) do (` And the rest of my script stays the same? So essentially I have two of these "for /F" statements, one nested in the other?